# Раритет и реликвия

Tags: семантика

Слова "раритет" и "реликвия" близки по смыслу: что-то старое/древнее, ценное не в материальном смысле, а, скорее, своей редкостью.

Чем же отличаются смыслы этих слов? Может, в слове "реликвия" есть оттенок "памятности", посвящения какому-либо лицу, событию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реликвия подразумевает некую святыню. Не обязательно религиозного толка, но явно вещь для кого-то очень значимую и бережно хранимую. А раритет — это просто редкость, уникальная вещь.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, разница именно в отношении.

Comment: Именно по этой причине реликвией может оказаться не обязательно очень старая вещь

Comment: Получается, что оба - и раритет, и реликвия - напрямую не связаны с "древностью" вещи. Скорее это "редкость" и "значимость". Но и то и другое увеличивается с годами!

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем-то да, реликвия связана с чем-то конкретным... Но главное все-таки уникакльность реликвии.

Comment: Я посмотрела, вроде слово "реликвия" имеет оттенок поклонения (особенно религиозная или историческая). Что-то подобное чувствуется и в сочетании "семейная реликвия".  
Но все же Вики-определения меня не совсем удовлетворили... 

А раритет не уникален? Редок уж точно!

Comment: Именно редок. Но никак не уникален. Смотрите сколько всяких раритетнх монет, раритетных книг, марок...
Книжка, конечно, тоже может стать реликвией, но для этого её должен подердать в руках какой-нибудь святой или она должна стать военным трофеем, или ещё что-нибудь такое, что выделит её из общего ряда.

Comment: А если держал в руках не святой, а злодей? Тоже уникально, но реликвия ли?...

Comment: Вот это вряд ли... Если только потом она не стала каким-то трофеем.
Понимаете, реликвии - ведь еще объект некоего преклонения, а не просто восхищения стариной.